SNR (Signal to noise ratio) from image
I have JWST images across 7 filters. I extracted sources by using SExtractor. How can I estimate the SNR of each source in each filter. Should I use flux/flux_err or use flux/background_rms. (flux and flux_err are in units of counts and background_rms is the value given by SExtractor) ?

Flux/Flux_err is the signal to noise ratio of your flux measurement.
